# React Redux TypeError: Cannot add property _, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

This website allows users to store collections of links and each collection has multipole categories and each category can have multiple entries:

```js
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Categories, Collection } from '../TestData';
import {RandomId} from '../util/RandomId'


let categoryList = Categories

const categorySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'category',
  initialState: {
    value: categoryList,
    currentCollectionId: Collection[0].collectionId
  },
  reducers: {
    // Retrieve categories corresponding to collectionId
    getCategories: (state, { payload }) => {
      const collectionId = payload
      const latestCatList = []

      // Find the categories corresponding with the collectionId
      categoryList.map((item) => {
        if (item.collectionId === collectionId) {
          latestCatList.push(item)
        }
      })
      //Update the category list the categories
      state.value = [...latestCatList]
      //Update the current collectionId state
      state.currentCollectionId = collectionId
      return state
    },
    // Add new category
    addCategory: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newCategory = {
        collectionId: state.currentCollectionId,
        catId: RandomId(),
        name: payload.name,
        listEntries: payload.listEntries
      }
      state.value.push(newCategory) // Add new category object to state
      state.value = [...state.value]
            
      // NEED TO ADD CATEOGRY TO TEST DATA BUT FOR SOME GODDAMN REASON ITS NOT, maybe push to database straight instead
      categoryList.push(newCategory)
    },
  }   
})
```

So I am using `react-redux` and in a component when I click a button its calling the `addCategory` action. I have a `Category` array of objects in another file that I exported and imported in this file like this. So the main way I'm doing this is I have to store the entire list of categories in another file (which I will use backend to pull the necessary categories associated to each user), and because some categories might be tied to different collections so I have a `getCategories` reducer that retrieve the appropriate `Categories` based on the current collection you are in. So each time I add category I need to add to the current state as well as the `Categories` array in the other file:

But for some reason it gives giving this error when I try to push the new object to the original category array:

ERROR:

> ```
> categorySlice.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 3, object is not extensible
> at Array.push (<anonymous>)
> at addCategory (categorySlice.js:36:1)
> at createReducer.ts:294:1
> at produce (immerClass.ts:94:1)
> at createReducer.ts:293:1
> at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
> at reducer (createReducer.ts:260:1)
> at reducer (createSlice.ts:372:1)
> at combination (redux.js:560:1)
> at E (<anonymous>:1:33326)
> ```

This is the category array:

```js
export const Categories = [
  {
    collectionId: '1232', // Reference the collection the categories are under
    catId: '1232019283',
    name: 'FIT 2099', // Name of category
    listEntries: [ // Array of objects for each list entry
      {
        name: 'Assignment 1',
        link: 'Ed forums FIT 2099_ A1'
      },
      {
        name: 'Assignment 2',
        link: 'Ed forums FIT 2099_ A2'
      },
    ] 
  },
  {
    collectionId: '1232',
    catId: '1232120398',
    name: 'FIT 2004',
    listEntries: [
      {
        name: 'Tutorial 2',
        link: 'Master theore,'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    collectionId: '1231',
    catId: '123109101',
    name: 'Movie List',
    listEntries: [
      {
        name: 'Harry potter 1',
        link: 'Hurawatch HP 1'
      }
    ] 
  },
]
```

I did some searching and I am not calling `preventExtensions` anywhere so is something automatically calling it? But makes sense, I tried even just copying the array by using spread operator or changing `const` to `var` nothing works.

Comment: The error mentions categorySlice.js line 36.  Can't see that part.  Provide code as text not images please.

Comment: sorry bout that new to stack overflow posting, added the code!

Comment: Please read through the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), because it explicitly also covers not using images for text: whether it's code or errors or console output, put it in your post as text with code markup where appropriate. Do _not_ use images of text.

Comment: Ah my bad, yea I changed all the images to actual text or code

Comment: What is `categoryList`? Please [edit] to include all relevant code you have an issue using and working with as part of a complete [mcve].

Comment: edited it ! Sorry missed out the top bit when I copy and pasted

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is definitely not safe - your reducer has a side effect.

This reducer could very well run 100 times with the same `state` and `action`. From Redux perspective, the `action` would have happened *once*, because it doesn't matter how often you execute a reducer - it will always return the same.

But since you are saving data to the side to `categoryList`, you would end up with 100 values in there.

What's worse, is that that is somehow part of your state, and somehow not. Your reducer here runs through `immer`, which replaces your whole object with a draft copy, and then "seals" the result so it cannot be changed any more. Taking something "out" during that process and then accessing it at a later time can be desastrous, as you found out.

You will have to keep your reducer pure. What you are doing here cannot work.

Why are you doing this in the first place? It seems very workaroundy.